# How to solve EOF Error in the below code?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, eoferror

In the below code I am getting EOF error in line 2. But I found noting wrong in the code. Can someone please help me with the solution.

**Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
a = int(input())
while a != 0:
    initial_time = input()
    initial_time = datetime.strptime(initial_time, "%I:%M %p")
    n = int(input())
    emp_str = ""
    while n != 0:
        inp = input()
        start_time = datetime.strptime(inp[:8], "%I:%M %p")
        end_time = datetime.strptime(inp[9:], "%I:%M %p")
        if initial_time >= start_time and end_time >= initial_time:
            emp_str += "1"
        else:
            emp_str += "0"
        n -= 1
    print(emp_str)
    a -= 1
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 2, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue using try and except block as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
try:
    a = int(input())
    
    while a != 0:
        initial_time = input()
        initial_time = datetime.strptime(initial_time, "%I:%M %p")
        n = int(input())
        emp_str = ""
        while n != 0:
            inp = input()
            start_time = datetime.strptime(inp[:8], "%I:%M %p")
            end_time = datetime.strptime(inp[9:], "%I:%M %p")
            if initial_time >= start_time and end_time >= initial_time:
                emp_str += "1"
            else:
                emp_str += "0"
            n -= 1
        print(emp_str)
        a -= 1
        
except EOFError as e:
    pass
```